# reinterpret_cast casts away qualifiers

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I add an issue on reinterpreting a variable and I don't know why..

```cpp
int ProgressBar(const uint64_t data_sent, const uint64_t data_total, void const *const data)
{
    Dialog *dialog = reinterpret_cast<Dialog*> (data);
    dialog->setValue((data_sent *100) / data_total);
}
```

the `reinterpret_cast` seems not allowed and say

> reinterpret_cast from 'const void *) to Dialog * casts away qualifiers

Any idea

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` can't cast away cv-qualifiers

Comment: @Nick: The last `const` you put in there has no effect.

Comment: Um, why are you trying to get rid of the `const` here? That sounds unsafe.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As Nick Strupat stated in comment,

> reinterpret_cast can't cast away cv-qualifiers

So you can use `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` together.

```
Dialog *dialog = const_cast<Dialog*>(reinterpret_cast<const Dialog *>(data));
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to also use a `const_cast` to remove `const` qualifiers. Also, casting from `void *` can use `static_cast`, it does not need to reinterpret. For example:

```
Dialog const *dialog = static_cast<Dialog const *>(data);
Dialog *d2 = const_cast<Dialog *>(dialog);
```

However , make sure that the Dialog is actually not a `const` object; attempting to modify a const object (presumably `setValue` does this) causes undefined behaviour.

I'd suggest rethinking the interface to `ProgressBar` to avoid needing this cast.