# Qualifier-losing conversion C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

The following code fails to compile in both MSVC2015 and clang when the comment marks are removed but it compiles as it is.

```
int main()
{
    static_assert( alignof( int * ) == alignof( int * * ), "nope" );

    const int * * a = nullptr;
    //const int * * * b = reinterpret_cast< const int * * * >( a );
    auto c = static_cast< const int * * * >( static_cast< void * >( a ) );
    return 0;
}
```

This question is different from a [previously asked one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995692/reinterpret-cast-casts-away-qualifiers) because there is not overall `const` qualifier being casted away.

According to the standard [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to `cv T`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`.

In this case, the target “pointer to `cv T`” is `const int * * *` which makes `T = const int * *` and no `cv` qualifiers. Thus, the result should be `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(v))`.

There are constrains about the alignment of `T`, but those are not relevant here as demonstrated in the static assert. Since the result of `reinterpret_cast< const int * * * >( a )` can actually be computed using the intermediate steps, the commented code should compile if uncommented.

Where is the error in my reasoning (if any)?

Comment: This is forbidden as per [expr.const.cast]p8, via [expr.reinterpret.cast]p2.

Comment: @dyp: I read [expr.const.cast]p8 "Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.", but I think it should not apply here because there are no function pointers involved.

Comment: You're quoting [expr.reinterpret.cast]p8. I was referring to [expr.const.cast]p8 and [expr.reinterpret.cast]p2.

Comment: Yes, I misread your comment ;-)

Answer (score 2):

N3690 5.2.11/8:

> The following rules define the process known as *casting away constness*.  In these rules `Tn` and `Xn` represent types.  For two pointer types:
>
> `X1` is `T1` *cv*<sub>1,1</sub> `*` ... *cv*<sub>1,*N*</sub> `*` where `T1` is not a pointer type
>
> `X2` is `T2` *cv*<sub>2,1</sub> `*` ... *cv*<sub>2,*M*</sub> `*` where `T2` is not a pointer type
>
> *K* is min(*N*,*M*)
>
> casting from `X1` to `X2` casts away constness if, for a non-pointer type `T` there does not exist an implicit conversion (Clause 4) from:
>
> `T` *cv*<sub>1,(*N*-*K*+1)</sub> `*` *cv*<sub>1,(*N*-*K*+2)</sub> `*` ... *cv*<sub>1,*N*</sub> `*`
>
> to
>
> `T` *cv*<sub>2,(*M*-*K*+1)</sub> `*` *cv*<sub>2,(*M*-*K*+2)</sub> `*` ... *cv*<sub>2,*M*</sub> `*`

In your example, `X1` is `const int**`, so *N* is 2, `T1` is `int`, *cv*<sub>1,1</sub> is `const`, and *cv*<sub>1,2</sub> is empty.  `X2` is `const int***`, so *M* is 3, `T2` is `int`, *cv*<sub>2,1</sub> is `const`, and *cv*<sub>2,2</sub> and *cv*<sub>2,3</sub> are empty.  *K* is 2.  Does there exist an implicit conversion from

`T` *cv*<sub>1,1</sub> `*` *cv*<sub>1,2</sub> `*` = `T const**`

to

`T` *cv*<sub>2,2</sub> `*` *cv*<sub>2,3</sub> `*` = `T**`?

No; therefore your cast casts away constness.

And of course we have 5.2.10/2:

> The `reinterpret_cast` operator shall not cast away constness (5.2.11).

Comment: Which version of the standard/draft are you using?