# reinterpret_cast<const> casts away const qualifier?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, const-correctness, function-qualifier

In the following case I try to cast a pointer to a struct into a pointer to another struct (which has the same memory layout behind the scenes). I try to do this in a const correct way, however the compiler is complaining.

I looked at a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995692/reinterpret-cast-casts-away-qualifiers) but I need the constness to propagate and it doesn't work like described for me.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%0Astruct+queue%0A%7B%0A++++//+...%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atypedef+struct+queue*+queue_handle%3B%0A%0Astruct+dummy_queue%0A%7B%0A++++//+...%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+queue_wrapper%0A%7B%0A++++auto+get_queue()+const+-%3E+queue_handle+%7B%0A++++++++return+reinterpret_cast%3Cconst+queue_handle%3E(%26d)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++dummy_queue+d%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++queue_wrapper+w%3B%0A++++w.get_queue()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:66.07329842931937,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.92670157068063,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
struct queue
{
    // ...
};

typedef struct queue* queue_handle;

struct dummy_queue
{
    // ...
};

struct queue_wrapper
{
    auto get_queue() const -> queue_handle {
        return reinterpret_cast<const queue_handle>(&d);
    }

    dummy_queue d;
};

int main()
{
    queue_wrapper w;
    w.get_queue();
}
```

**Error:**

```
<source>: In member function 'queue* queue_wrapper::get_queue() const':
<source>:17:16: error: 'reinterpret_cast' from type 'const dummy_queue*' to type 'queue_handle' {aka 'queue*'} casts away qualifiers
   17 |         return reinterpret_cast<const queue_handle>(&d);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm converting to a const pointer though (which gcc seems to misunderstand somehow). I do not need to change the pointer after returning it. How do I accomplish this conversion without errors?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not for adding/removing cv-qualifiers. One possible solution is `typedef struct queue const* queue_handle;`

Comment: `queue_handle` is a pointer to a non-const `queue`, but `d` is `const` in `get_queue()`. Are you sure you want to return a non-const pointer to a const member? Why is `get_queue()` declared as `const` in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const queue_handle` applies the `const` to the pointer type itself, not the pointed to type as you intent to.

I would suggest adding a `const_queue_handle` alias to `const queue*` if you are already using aliases for the pointers (whether or not that is a good idea is a matter of opinion) and then you can use that as template argument to `reinterpret_cast`.

Also beware that even if the struct layout is identical, this is still undefined behavior territory. A compiler may assume that a pointer to one of the struct types won't alias one to the other and use that for optimization. You should probably at least compile everything with `-fno-strict-aliasing` when doing this.